# Check if a circular path exists given a string input as a list of moves

Tags: java, string, list, algorithm

This is a similar question to https://leetcode.com/problems/robot-bounded-in-circle/

The only difference is our input for the function is a List and we need to return "YES" or "NO" for reach command based on if we go in a circle or not.

My current does not pass all the test cases. I have provided the code and one of the test cases it does not pass:

```
public statis List<String> doesCircleExist(List<String> commands) {

    List<String> results = new ArrayList<>();

    for (String command : commands) {
      int currX = 0;
      int currY = 0;
      int currDir = 0;
      // north east south west
      int[][] dir = { { 0, 1 }, { 1, 0 }, { 0, -1 }, { -1, 0 } };
      for (char c : command.toCharArray()) {
        switch (c) {
        case 'G':
          currX += dir[currDir][0];
          currY += dir[currDir][1];
          break;
        case 'R':
          currDir = (currDir + 1) % 4;
          break;
        case 'L':
          currDir -= 1;
          if (currDir < 0)
            currDir = 3;
          break;
        }
      }
      if (currX == 0 && currY == 0) {
        results.add("YES");
      } else {
        results.add("NO");
      }
    }
    return results;
  }
}
```

```
Input std(in)
3
6
L
RGRG

Your output
NO
YES
NO

Expected output
NO
YES
YES
```

Comment: You've already found the problem on an external site, which has solutions/explanations there, so what is there to be gained by posting here? You already know which case(s) your algorithm fails to work on; the first step would be to figure out why the answer to those cases are yes/no and then reconsider your approach. As a hint, `RGRG` expects `YES` because, after running that set of instructions twice, it'll end at the origin.

Answer (score -1):

Since this is essentially a 2 - dimension problem, and assuming that the definition of a circle is that at some point you get to the starting point, I would just use 2d coordinates, with the starting point set as [0,0].

You can parse the path sequentially, and use some flag variables to track where are you facing.

From this point, its just a matter of increasing/decreasing the first coordinate when going left/right, and increasing/decreasing the second coordinate when going up/down.

Then, after each step if you happen to find yourself at [0,0], then you know you travelled a "circle".